# ALAsset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation undeclared?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, alasset

This might seem too easy or maybe it's just confusing for me... Or maybe I'm too tired to think rationally.

I am trying to get the location of an UIImage that has been selected by the user from the photo album using imagePickerController.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *pic = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic, 0.01f);
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    bookmarkImage.image = image1;

    NSLog(@"new image size = %i", [data length]);

    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
    4NSLog(@"%@",url);

    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultBlock = ^(ALAsset *myAsset){
        [myAsset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
    };

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now, where I try to call the **valueForProperty** for ALAsset is where I have trouble. This is the error I'm getting:

Use of undeclared identifier 'ALAssetPropertyLocation'.

Please help! This is getting really frustrating... I need the location of the photo...

Comment: are you on iOS 4.0+? have you check your imports for: #import <AssetsLibrary/ALAsset.h>

Comment: NO! I just did it and it fixed the problem!

Comment: the only import that I had was #import "AssetsLibrary/ALAssetsLibrary.h" which I thought it's the correct one... thank you very much!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's pretty silly but I've been missing an import:

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/ALAsset.h>
```

Thanks to markus who pointed it out!