# How to load images from Gallery to UiImageView in XCODE5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

Hi 
I am getting a problem in load images from the gallery to `UIImageView` in Xcode 5.

When I am trying to get images from the Gallery in `UIImage` it will generate exceptional error in my screen.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code. Also show the error you are getting

Comment: What's the error? Did you granted access to Gallery?

Comment: hello ankit may this url help you:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633843/get-all-of-the-pictures-from-an-iphone-photolibrary-in-an-array-using-assetslibr

Comment: @kamaleshkumaryadav : Thank You May be this will help me...

Comment: Actually i don't have any code right now i just want to make one programme like that kind of facility. please suggest me some links or Programmes

Comment: yes ankit do u want to to select one image from galary or you want to import all image

Comment: @kamaleshkumaryadav : i want to import all the images from the gallery.

Comment: hello ankit first off all you try by yourself and above url provide you some knowledge to fetch image.If it not done then post your code that you tried and problem.

Comment: @kamaleshkumaryadav : Thanks for all the help....Program Run successfully...

Answer (score 4):

You can use following method to load image from gallery. 
You have to call `methodToCallPhotos` when you click on gallery button.

```
-(void)methodToCallPhotos
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

}
```

After this when you select any image from the gallery. It calls delegate method like below

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
              editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    imageView.image = image;
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if your app is granted permission to access Photo gallery.

Have a look at the documentation for ALAssetsLibrary [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html). To access all photos and videos you need to enumerate all groups (albums) in the photo library and then enumerate all photos and images in each group.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[al enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll

    usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
        {
            if (asset)
            {                
                 .. do something with the asset
            }
        }
    }

    failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
    {
        .. handle error 
    }
 ];
```