# Video thumbnail image from directory

Tags: ios, video, ios7

I am a newbie in iOS.I want to show a video thumbnail in image view such that by clicking a Button it should open a gallery and by selecting a video it should display the video thumbnail...... please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are videos and images that stored on photo library, firstly you want to get all videos from the library, prior to iOS 8, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633843/get-all-of-the-pictures-from-an-iphone-photolibrary-in-an-array-using-assetslibr) shows you how to fetch pictures using AssetsLibrary library. You can filter videos out when doing it, then you get an ALAsset, which can represent a image or video, suppose when you select a video, you get a ALAsset named asset, using the below function will get you a thumbnail image for that video.

If you use ALAsset.

```
UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]];
```

For iOS 8, apple introduces a new Photos library,you can fetch all videos from the library as above, a video or images is represented by PHAsset, suppose you have a PHAsset ivar named asset, you can use the following method to get a UIImage from this asset. Take a look at [requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHImageManager/requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:), you can set the target size to the size of the thumb image you want,in the resultHandler,you get the UIImage.

Comment: can u plz explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I am using below code to get thumbnail of video which is downloaded in document directory,

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailFromVideoAtURL:(NSURL *)url
{
   AVURLAsset *aImgAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
   AVAssetImageGenerator *aImgGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] aImgAsset];
   aImgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
   NSError *err = NULL;
   CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 2);
   CGImageRef aImgRef = [aImgGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
   UIImage *aImgThumb = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:aImgRef];

   return aImgThumb;
}
```