# Get all Images from iphone image library and show in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, assetslibrary

I want to show all the images from iphone image library to `UICollectionView` but after finished getAllPictures method, `allPhotosCollected`: method is not calling and images is not showing into `UICollectionView`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self getAllPictures];
} 

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [imageArray count];
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];

    return cell;
}


-(void)getAllPictures
{
    imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
    mutableArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray* assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if(result != nil) {
            if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto]) {
                [assetURLDictionaries addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];

                NSURL *url= (NSURL*) [[result defaultRepresentation]url];

                [library assetForURL:url
                         resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                             [mutableArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]]];



                                 imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutableArray];
                                 [self allPhotosCollected:imageArray];

                         }
                        failureBlock:^(NSError *error){ NSLog(@"operation was not successfull!"); } ];

            }
        }
    };

    NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    void (^ assetGroupEnumerator) ( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)= ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if(group != nil) {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
            [assetGroups addObject:group];
            count=[group numberOfAssets];
        }
    };

    assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                           usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                         failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {NSLog(@"There is an error");}];

}


-(void)allPhotosCollected:(NSArray*)imgArray
{
    NSLog(@"all pictures are %@",imgArray);
    [self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633843/get-all-of-the-pictures-from-an-iphone-photolibrary-in-an-array-using-assetslibr

Comment: If you have so many images then it will take much memory to load.try with less number of images

Comment: I have only 2 images

Comment: @KiritModi i already check this question but but not getting proper answer

Comment: use the demo . https://github.com/chiunam/CTAssetsPickerController

Answer (score 2):

Can you please see the following code. I hope it will be helpful to you.

Get all image from gallery

**View Controller header(.h) file..**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h> 

@interface getPhotoLibViewController : UIViewController
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library;
    NSArray *imageArray;
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray;
}

-(void)allPhotosCollected:(NSArray*)imgArray;

@end
```

**implementation file(.m)**

declare global count variable as

```
static int count=0;

@implementation getPhotoLibViewController

-(void)getAllPictures
{
    imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
    mutableArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray* assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(result != nil) {
    if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto]) {
      [assetURLDictionaries addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];

    NSURL *url= (NSURL*) [[result defaultRepresentation]url]; 

    [library assetForURL:url
             resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                 [mutableArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]]];

                 if ([mutableArray count]==count)
                 {
                     imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutableArray];
                     [self allPhotosCollected:imageArray];
                 }
             }
            failureBlock:^(NSError *error){ 
                NSLog(@"operation was not successfull!"); 
            } ]; 

        } 
    }
    };

    NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    void (^ assetGroupEnumerator) ( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)= ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if(group != nil) {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
            [assetGroups addObject:group];
            count=[group numberOfAssets];
        }
    };

    assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                        usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                      failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"There is an error");
    }];
}

 -(void)allPhotosCollected:(NSArray*)imgArray
 {
      //write your code here after getting all the photos from library...
      NSLog(@"all pictures are %@",imgArray);
 }
```

@end
Use getAllPicture method to get photos from photo library.

OR You can have a look at this blog http://mutiselectimagepicker.blogspot.in/2014/08/imageselect-to-allow-multiple-selection.html

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to *reload collectionView data*, insert this line of code after fetching all images:

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

However, I would recommend you to use Photos Framework instead of ALAssetsLibrary as ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated. Here [(link)](https://github.com/ArpitOnTheWay/Photos_Framework_Example) is an example of Photos Framework getting all videos, you have to modify it for getting Photos instead of Videos.