# how can i select multiple photos from camera roll in xcode without using third party?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I m trying to search how to select multiple photos in image picker view but all are giving suggestion to use third party classes from git hub but i want to do it without third party.. please help me

Comment: You can't do using `UIImagePickerController`, it doesn't have that capability, but Yes, you don't even need a third party you can simply fetch all the photo using `AssetsLibrary` and load into a UICollectionView and implement your logic (see this)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/12634165/790842], if you don't want to implement these logic, use `Third Party framework`.

Comment: Your only option is to write your own code, just like all the 3rd party options you've seen.