# how to get the location of Photos library

Tags: objective-c, macos

By defaults, the location of Photos Library is `"~/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary"` but the photosLibrary can be moved to other location and the Application Photos always know the new location of Library, how does Photos implement this . Or anyone can tell me how to get the location of library programmatically ?

Comment: What do you want to do? There is probably a smarter way than messing around with the path.

Comment: @HermannKlecker , i want to get images under that path and i update my question. Do you know is there any way to get the location of Library?

Comment: Not directly but you can use the AssetsLibrary to get all images. Once you found one there are even ways of finding the path name to the image file but I understand that you do not need the path then anymore. Just don't care where they are stored and use the AssetsLibrary. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633843/get-all-of-the-pictures-from-an-iphone-photolibrary-in-an-array-using-assetslibr

Comment: Is there a version for OSX @HermannKlecker

Comment: Apologies. I'll mend you rtags.