# How to insert all photos and videos from camera roll into array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, camera-roll

Is there a way to add everything from your camera roll to an array?

Comment: note that array you wanted can be too big to live in memory

Comment: oh ok, didn't think of that. What is the best way to have access to all photos and videos?

Comment: maybe `UIImagePickerController` can cover your needs?

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633843/get-all-of-the-pictures-from-an-iphone-photolibrary-in-an-array-using-assetslibr

Comment: no I don't want to use the UIImagePickerController. I want them to appear automatically without doing anything

Answer (score 0):

```
import Photos

class MyVC: UIViewController 
{
var images:NSMutableArray! // Array for storing images


func fetchPhotos () {
    images = NSMutableArray()
    self.fetchPhotoAtIndexFromEnd(0)
}


func getImageAtIndex(index:Int) {

    let imgManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()


    var requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.synchronous = true // if just return thumbnail not img

    // optionally sort the images by creation date
    var fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: false)]

    if let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptions) {


        if fetchResult.count > 0 {
            imgManager.requestImageForAsset(fetchResult.objectAtIndex(fetchResult.count - 1 - index) as PHAsset, targetSize: view.frame.size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (image, _) in

                // Add img to images array
                self.images.addObject(image)


                if index + 1 < fetchResult.count {
                    self.fetchPhotoAtIndexFromEnd(index + 1)
                } else {

                    println("Completed array: \(self.images)")
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is fetchPhotoAtIndexFromEnd?